# When, if ever, is it OK to put OAuth client secrets in source code?

Tags: security, oauth

I was browsing the source code of the GitHub CLI and I was surprised to find that their client secret is [baked in](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/7d558edd12d6b4101a0b3d3df3c689385a1c830a/internal/authflow/flow.go#L21-L25) like this:

```golang
var (
    // The "GitHub CLI" OAuth app
    oauthClientID = "178c6fc778ccc68e1d6a"
    // This value is safe to be embedded in version control
    oauthClientSecret = "34ddeff2b558a23d38fba8a6de74f086ede1cc0b"

    jsonTypeRE = regexp.MustCompile(`[/+]json($|;)`)
)
```

How is it safe for GitHub to embed this secret? Would it be safe for me to do this with my own CLI app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client secrets shouldn't be exposed in version control systems, especially in public repositories. They shouldn't also be baked into any code that is available to your users (e.g. code of a mobile app, or Javascript code available in the browser).

I assume (and hope) that here GitHub treats the client as a public client. There might be a technical reason why they have to also send the client secret to some endpoints. In this sense, it's OK to put the secret into the code/VC. You just treat it as part of the client ID. However, this is not a very common use case.